# Smart Table Module of Angularjs - issue related to handling it's directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

Probably there is some mistake from my end in handling the syntax and presentation in Angular.

This code is not working

http://plnkr.co/edit/sR3gqODKoqL6utxsXqQu?p=preview

Same code is working in this way

http://plnkr.co/edit/W3GQZaIu5vPFza7aBOA6?p=preview

Please check the `script.js` file there in the file where things are working properly the directive and app is all linked to each other an then where it isn't working I tried separating it which I must do in order to accommodate it in a separate view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have forgot var app ont top of script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);
```